# Array change the values automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic4

```
....
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
...
```

I´m reading a file .xlsx in Ionic 4

```
showData() {
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
    let data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
    let arr = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    let bstr = arr.join("");
    let  workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
    let first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
    let rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<Income>(worksheet, { raw: true });

    this.allIncomesFromDocument = rows 
    this.Test(rows)    
  }
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
}

Test(rows){
  this.allIncomesFromDocument.forEach( v => console.log(v.quantity) ) // FIRST LOG

  rows.forEach( row =>{
    row.quantity = 0;
  })

  this.allIncomesFromDocument.forEach( v => console.log(v.quantity) ) // SECCOND LOG
}
```

In the fisrt Log I have

```
8
7
5
9
2
etc.
```

the data that I have in the file

but I never change the values and only repit the same forEache and the log I have

```
0
0
0
ect.
```

The logs are completely different

Comment: from the first log, the array has quantity of 8,7,5,9,2, etc, but then just before the second log, you do row.quantity = 0; for each row. therefore when you console.log the v.quantity, every row now has quantity of 0

Comment: Yes is correctr, but I save the data original in **this.allIncomesFromDocument** 
 and never asing new values, if you pay attention the forEach is with the data send on the parameters on the method.

never in **this.allIncomesFromDocument**

Comment: isn't it the same as: var rows = [{quantity: 1},{quantity: 2},{quantity: 3}];

var allIncome = rows;

rows.forEach(row => row.quantity = 0);

console.log(allIncome);

Comment: the above code will log quantity as 0

Comment: I need save the original data in an Array
and edit the data in other array, but if change one the other is changed too

Comment: yes, they are pointing at the same object in memory.. if you need another array, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this 
`this.allIncomesFromDocument = rows`
you are actually assigning a **reference** not **copying** the data.

This means that when you do this
`row.quantity = 0;`
You are updating the **reference**, which is both variables.

If you change 
`this.allIncomesFromDocument = rows`
to
`this.allIncomesFromDocument = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))`
You will create a full copy of the data rather than just assigning the reference.

Comment: As @glen-k points out above, you could also use Object.assign rather than JSON, just depends on what Javascript version you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks guys both answers work fine, I've never used  Object.assign();, but is clearly.
I prefer use JSON, less code, but I don´t know if is the best option I'll check the Object.assign in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you would have to assign two arrays.. and one of the array would have to use Object.assign to prevent the mutation of the original object. Ex:

```
var rows = [{quantity: 1},{quantity: 2},{quantity: 3}];

var allIncome = rows;

let newIncome = rows.map(row => {
  let newRow = Object.assign({}, row);
  newRow.quantity = 0;
  return newRow;
});

console.log(allIncome);
console.log(newIncome);
```